# MySQL Group By: How exclude group if at least one row contain value?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, having-clause

How do you filter out a group in the HAVING clause if at least one row of the group meets some condition? For example, If have the following table:

[image]

And I want group by `id1` and `id2` and exclude any group where at least one of its rows has "value" in the `someText` column ? So in my results, the group (1,1) should be excluded but (1,2), (2,1) and (2,3) should be returned. Preferably, I am looking for a solution using the HAVING clause(this is just a simple example to illustrate the problem - but I am working on large query))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` with a conditional expression:

```
select id1, id2
from mytable
group by id1, id2
having max(someText = 'value') = 0
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Why does max work like this?

Comment: @oneCoderToRuleThemAll: in this context, `someText = 'value'` returns 1 if the condition is fullfilled, else 0. So `max((someText = 'value') = 0` means: there is no value in the group that satisfy the condition.

Comment: How does MySQL evaluate this? Does it iterate through all values of `someText` column for that group, apply this boolean expression to each one, pick out the maximum value(which would be 1 if the value is present) ?